# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {className} java.lang.IllegalStateException: No colors found! (Android JetPack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Android Jetpack Compose, trying to create a List of buttons with Column but app is crashing by throwing error as

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.sample.composeUI/com.sample.composeUI.ui.homeScreen.HomeScreenActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No colors found!

Code:

```
@Composable
fun homeScreenCompose() {

    Column(
        crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.Center,
        mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Center,
        modifier = Spacing(16.dp)
    ) {
        Button(
            text = "ListView", onClick = {
            }, style = ContainedButtonStyle(
                color = Color.White,
                shape = RectangleShape,
                rippleColor = Color.DarkGray,
                elevation = Dp(4f)
            ))
    }
}
```

Not able to find the route cause of this issue, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android compose use Material design internally to provide color and typograpy to your view. So you need to wrap your function inside `MaterialTheme composable function`.

```
@Composable
fun homeScreenCompose() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Column(
            crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.Center,
            mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Center,
            modifier = Spacing(16.dp)
        ) {
            Button(
                text = "ListView", onClick = {
                }, style = ContainedButtonStyle(
                    color = Color.White,
                    shape = RectangleShape,
                    rippleColor = Color.DarkGray,
                    elevation = Dp(4f)
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This error case occur when you are using compose `0.1.0-dev02` version. It is not necessary for `0.1.0-dev03` version.